# How do I calculate the average rating of the detail rating?

Tags: php

My code is like this :

```
<?php 
    $rating = 5;
    $rating_detail = '{"3":"1","4":"2"}';
    $array_data = json_decode($rating_detail, true);
    if(array_key_exists($rating, $array_data)) {
        $value = $array_data[$rating];
        if ($value !== false) {
            $array_data[$rating] = (string)((int)$value + 1);
        }
        $rating_detail = json_encode($array_data);
    }
    else {
        $data = substr($rating_detail, 0, -1);
        $rating_detail = $data.',"'.$rating.'":"1"}';
    }

    echo '<pre>';print_r($rating_detail);echo '</pre>';die();
?>
```

If the code run, the result like this :

> {"3":"1","4":"2","5":"1"}

It's detail rating of a store

Note :

3 = rating 3, 1 = Number of users giving ratings : 1

4 = rating 4, 2 = Number of users giving ratings : 2

5 = rating 5, 1 = Number of users giving ratings : 1

How do I calculate the average rating of the detail rating?

So the average rating of the detail rating of a store is between 1 - 5

Update

So from here :

> {"3":"1","4":"2","5":"1"}

Based on the detail of that rating, how do I calculate the rating of a store?

Comment: what's your expected result?

Comment: You don't know what is __average__?

Comment: @Val, `{"3":"1","4":"2","5":"1"}`

Comment: @u_mulder,I just want to make sure the calculations are correct

Comment: @SuccessMan Thats actually not your expected result. Your expected result would be ((3*1)+(4*2)+(5+1)) / 4 = 4. So your expected result is 4.

Comment: (3+4+4+5)/4=4 is that what you want ?

Comment: @Twinfriends, Why is it for 4?
4 from where?

Comment: @Abid, Why is it for 4? 4 from where?

Comment: @SuccessMan Because you asked for the average?! Do you know how to calculate the avaerage of some numbers, or do you have no idea about how to calculate averages? Thats something you learn in the really early classes in school....

Comment: @Twinfriends, Why divided by 4? Should be divided by 3

Comment: @SuccessMan No, not at all. You have one user who voted "3", one user who voted "5" and TWO users who voted "4" - so you have to devide by 4. Average is always calculated by summ up all numbers and then divide it by the number of numbers you added. In this case, you added 4 numbers together, so you have to divide it by 4... no magic here.

Comment: because you have given four ratings in the example ... We can make it dynamic but for just knowing you expected result i used that example @SuccessMan

Comment: Okay. Thanks guys

Comment: @SuccessMan No problem. For your future calculations, here the formula: 
`((3 * Number_of_people_who_voted_3) + (4 * number_of_oeple_who_voted_4) + (5 * Number_of_people_who_voted_5)) / total_number_of_people_who_voted` - If you have also ratings for 1 & 2, simply add them in the formula like the first three parts, shouldn't be that difficult, otherwise feel free to ask again :)

Comment: @Twinfriends, Okay. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$rating = 5;
$rating_detail = '{"3":"1","4":"2"}';
$rating_detail = json_decode($rating_detail, true);
if(array_key_exists($rating, $rating_detail)) {
        $rating_detail[$rating] = (string)((int)$rating_detail[$rating] + 1);
}
else {
    $rating_detail[$rating]="1";
}
$totalStar=$totalRate=0;
foreach ($rating_detail as $key=>$value){
    $totalStar+=$key*$value;
    $totalRate+=$value;

}
$average=$totalStar/$totalRate;
```

It give out put as

[image]

Comment: @Success Man did you try this ?

Comment: Pleasure is mine :)